humbarger icon on mobile wont open the navigation
I am building a simple wordpress theme and in the navigation when browser shrunk to mobile size the humbarger icon appears but it wont open the nav as expected. I tried a few codes and I cant seem to find out whats wrong. Any help would be appriciated. Since this is a wordpress I wasnt able to do fiddle here:
appd4b.com is the live demo

<header>
 <nav class="navigation" id="myTopnav">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://appd4b.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/WEBD4B-removebg-preview.png" alt="Site Logo" width="15%" height="15%">
    </div>
    
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Project</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="humbarger icon" onclick="toggleMenu()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
</header>

and then In js file I have
function toggleMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "navigation") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navigation";
  }
}

And Css is rather straight forward


.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.logo {
  flex: 1;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.menu-list {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-list li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.menu-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.humbarger {
  display: none; /* Hide by default */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-list {
    display: none; /* Hide menu on smaller screens */
  }

  .humbarger {
    display: block; /* Show hamburger menu on smaller screens */
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }

  .bar2 {
    width: 20px; /* Adjust to create hamburger effect */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation .menu-list {
    display: none;
  }

  .navigation.responsive .menu-list {
    display: block;
  }
}



I was trying with javascirpt but if jquery is better I will do that

The CSS belonging to the relevant part, that makes the effect, is not present in the style.css. Include it and it will work.
Also, the menu items' visibility should be applied below 768px in order for the .hamburger menu to make sense, like so:
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-list {
    display: none; /* Hide menu on smaller screens */
  }

  .humbarger {
    display: block; /* Show hamburger menu on smaller screens */
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }

  .bar2 {
    width: 20px; /* Adjust to create hamburger effect */
  }
  .navigation .menu-list { /*missing from here*/
    display: none;
  }

  .navigation.responsive .menu-list {
    display: block;
  }
}


Can't believe I missed that thanks a million for your time
